# why there is opacity on image how to put no opacity on image and put hover function on div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the following image without any inherited opacity from the parent. The relevant code:

**CSS**

```
     #accordion ul {

        width:184px;
        display:none;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        opacity:0.70;
        list-style-type: none;  
    }

        #accordion ul li {

            width:184px;
            height:40px;
            margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            font-size:17px;
            color:#999999;
            background:url(img/green.png) no-repeat 8% 50%, url(img/back_line.png) ;


        }

        /* styling of submenu item */ 
        #accordion ul li img {

            padding: 7px 8px 0px 35px ;
            width:30px;
            height:30px;

        }

        #accordion ul li:hover{
            width:184px;
            height:40px;
            background:url(img/green.png) no-repeat 8% 50%,#D5D5D2;
        }

        /* remove border bottom of the last item */
        #accordion ul li.last {
            border-bottom: none;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item popular" rel="popular"></a>
        <ul id="inchat" class="list_friends">           
            <div><img src="facebook/49992_720384020_1896998575_q.jpg">Francois</div>
            <div><img src="facebook/48983_615523712_8495_q.jpg">Yue</div>
            <div><img src="facebook/41621_717814907_4472_q.jpg">Daivid</div>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item category" rel="category"></a>
        <ul id="inchannel">

            <div><img src="facebook/49992_720384020_1896998575_q.jpg">Francois</div>
            <div><img src="facebook/48983_615523712_8495_q.jpg">Yue</div>
            <div><img src="facebook/41621_717814907_4472_q.jpg">Daivid</div>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item comment" rel="comment"></a>
        <ul id="online">
            <div><img src="facebook/49992_720384020_1896998575_q.jpg">Francois</div>
            <div><img src="facebook/48983_615523712_8495_q.jpg">Yue</div>
            <div><img src="facebook/41621_717814907_4472_q.jpg">Daivid</div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The image has opacity from the parent that I do not want. Also, how do I put a `hover` style on a `div`?

Thank you.

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid. You cannot put a DIV directly after a UL.

Comment: Should i put li instead?

Comment: i did It works fine :) how to put no opacity on image?

Comment: You should research the levels of specificity for CSS at this [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done through becoming more specific with your CSS.

For the img CSS:

```
#accordion ul li img {
        opacity:0;    
    }
```

To hover using CSS:

```
#accordion div:hover {
     color:#FFF;
}
```